# Triggering a thread group at regular intervals

Tags: jmeter

I have 3 thread groups in my Jmeter scripts to send messages to activeMQ queues

```
1) Sends a message of Type A
2) Send a message of Type B
3) Checks if the out queue count has increased
```

I would like to check the out queue after sending each type of message. So i would like to do it in this order

```
1,3,2,3.
```

I know there is a sequential execution option at the Test plan level. However this would mean duplication of the out queue count check.

Answer (score 0):

1. Easier solution: move everything under a single Thread Group and put requests 1 and 2 under [Interleave Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller) like:

   - Interleave Controller

     - Sends a message of Type A
     - Send a message of Type B
   - Checks if the out queue count has increased

     [image: JMeter Interleave Controller]
2. If for some reason you cannot move requests into a singe Thread Group you can consider using [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin in order to perform a check only if a message has been sent. You can install Inter-Thread Communication Plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

   [image: JMeter Inter Thread Communication]